# rzc generate exited with code 1 Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets 3.0.0-preview8-28405-07

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, compiler-errors

just upgraded from core 2 to core 3 preview

```
 3.0.0-preview8-28405-07
```

there are no errors and then i build and get the cryptic error

```
rzc generate exited with code 1. 

/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview8-013656/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor.CodeGeneration.targets
```

is there any way to start knowing what is going wrong with the build? this error seems ubiquitous across the dotnet ecosystem since before core 3?

Comment: For this error, I suggest you try to refer this discussion [Blazor - rzc generate exited with code 1. DotNet Core 3.0.100-preview8-013656 #13115](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13115), and I would recommend you install the .net core 3.0 relase version.

Comment: You are using visual studio 2019 older version then you have updated to the latest version has fixed my issue.